# Gmail SMTP Suitable For Production Messaging

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have some automated emailing tasks set up in my application. That is every day I send application specific email to customers to remind them of appointments etc. Is using Gmail's smtp suitable for production tasks beyond just a simple message here any there? Is there any benefit to implementing my own smtp server such as Apache James?

Comment: "suitable for production use"?  Well, what do they guarantee you?  If it is really important, consider purchasing a guaranteed service level.

Comment: What is a guaranteed service level? Is that something I purchase from gmail?

Comment: Something like "We guarantee that 99.99% of the time our service will function as promised.  The more 9's the more expensive".  I would suggest calling Google if you cannot see this in their online documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Richthofen - Using gmail to send emails in a production environment is a bad (and unethical) idea; Amazon SES or Sendgrid are the best solutions here. If you want to run your own SMTP server then please keep in mind that it will share resources with your application and will probably slow it down.

However I use gmail to test development/testing environments using javamail API. Here's the code:

```
public class EmailSender{

    public void send(){
      //javamail code
      Session mailSession = createSmtpSession();
      //javamail code
    }

    private Session createSmtpSession() {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty ("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "" + 587);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty ("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        // props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");

        return Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                    "<gmail ID in user@domain format goes here>", 
                    "<password goes here>");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Unethical? I'd like to reiterate that I am not talking about sending spammy marketing email. My automated mail system is used only for sending transaction email such as appointment reminders, or registration confirmations.

Comment: Sorry I was still typing when you mentioned your purpose in the comment boxes above.. btw one of my clients uses a google apps email account  for email delivery to clients, including medium sized attachments, and its been very reliable

Answer (score 2):

Gmail TOS prohibits unsolicited commercial emails. In general I wouldn't deploy any service that relies on Gmail to the public. I think Gmail caps an email recipient list to 100 anyways so it would probably fail if you tried to send the same message to more than 100 people.

Usually you want your own IP for outgoing mail for reputation reasons. For most of my clients when I do freelance work I recommend affordable partner services like http://sendgrid.com/ ... Having your own IP means that you can manage your reputation as a bulk email sender legitimately. And you won't have to worry about Gmail shutting you down for breaking the TOS. Gmail also won't give you metrics about deliverability so you won't have any idea if you're being successful in sending these.

Having worked for a major email marketer, I can tell you that just sending a message to an SMTP server is not enough these days. All major mail service providers do things like require sender identification keys for bulk mail. They also meter messages and flag senders who end up submitting too many messages in a specific amount of time. If you want your mail delivered and not in the SPAM folder you need to do either a lot of work and spin up a dedicated server w/ a dedicated IP, or you should use a vendor who can do some of that work for you.

Comment: I do not think he wants to send spam, but instead want to know if Googles SMTP server can be relied on being up.

Comment: What is considered bulk email? I'm not talking about sending marketing email to thousands of people but more or less, running through my database, finding contacts that need a reminder message sent based on the specific day, and then sending out a custom generated message to each contact one by one with the reminder. Does this classify as bulk mailing? I'll also be using javamail to send out transactional email such as when a user registers.

Comment: Concerned with being up...yes, but i'm fairly confident in googles up time. I was more concerned on if gmail's smtp is meant to be used in situations like mine, or if implementing my own smtp server is more of a standard practise (considering I don't want to use another provider such as sendgrid). And the benefits to using my own smtp server. If there are no real benefits and gmail is sufficient, it doesn't make sense to expend the energy deploying my own servers...unless there is considerable benefits to doing so.

Comment: If you're sending transactional emails, most email providers consider transactional email 'bulk'. Technically, their spam filters will see the fact that you sent a slightly customized version to several people and consider it beyond the TOS.

I know you're not sending UNSOLICITED email, which is a totally different level of hell than regular spam. But the people in charge of enforcing Gmail service access/ TOS violations aren't going to nitpick. If you use Gmail, eventually someone will flag your email as spam even though they signed for the service, and you may get banned.